# Ruby - Iterate through records found with SQL statement

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a bunch of records found with this `SQL`

> select id from employee_holiday_years where start_date = '2015-01-01' and employee_id in(select id from employees where join_date > '2014-12-31') and allowance_from_last_year <> 0;

I need to iterate through the records returned by this `SQL` using Ruby and run a couple of Ruby commands against each one. Is this possible?

Comment: We need more information. How are you sending that SQL statement? Are you using the Active Record ORM or just a driver? Which one? Show us a minimal example of the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

By ruby you can try this lets you have `mysql` adapter and `ruby` installed Also you have

Database Name `TESTDB`
username `testuser`
password `test123`
host:      `localhost`

```
  require "dbi"

  begin  
   dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:TESTDB:localhost", 
                    "testuser", "test123")
   sth = dbh.prepare("select id from employee_holiday_years where start_date = '2015-01-01' and employee_id in(select id from employees where join_date > '2014-12-31') and allowance_from_last_year <> 0;")
   sth.execute(1000)

   #iterate through the return records 
   sth.fetch do |row|
    printf row[0], row[1] #to print the row

   end
   sth.finish

  rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
   puts "An error occurred"
   puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
   puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
  ensure
   # disconnect from server
   dbh.disconnect if dbh
  end
```

For more [Ruby Database Access](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_database_access.htm)

Answer (score 0):

sql return Array so use Array iteration.

e.g

```
recoreds.each do |record|
  p record.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database => "mydatabase")
results = client.query("select * from mytable where...", :symbolise_keys => true)

results.each do |row|
  do stuff...
end
```